# no rule to make target works after second time

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

In one of my included Makefiles is a rule for `%.kt_rfgw`. When i first compile, there is `No rule to make target` and it failed. But when i do make a second time without any changes it will find the rules except the webserver doesn't need to rebuild.

Makefile:

```
TARGET:=kt_rfgw

all: webserver gateway

webserver:
  ...doing stuff...

gateway: $(CONTIKI_PROJECT).$(TARGET)
  ...doing stuff...
```

In a Makefile.Include:

```
$(warning Rule: "%.kt_rfgw:" found)%.$(TARGET): %.co $(PROJECT_OBJECTFILES) $(PROJECT_LIBRARIES) contiki-$(TARGET).a
...doing stuff...
```

Error-Message when do make first time:

```
/c/...path.../Makefile.include:316: Rule: "%.kt_rfgw:" found
...
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `regelfern.kt_rfgw', needed by `gateway'.  Stop.
```

No-Message when do make first time:

```
/c/...path.../Makefile.include:316: Rule: "%.kt_rfgw:" found
...
...compiling...
```

Comment: Please include the rule for `%.kt_rfgw`. Ideally strip out all the unnecessary stuff and create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `$(TARGET)` is `%.kt_rfgw`, sorry

Comment: I think the problem is, that the target `gateway` needs a file which will created by the target `webserver`. But only at the very beginng the rules where checked for the target `gateway`. Is it possible to check again before starting the second target?

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to tell make that the `webserver` rule builds `$(CONTIKI_PROJECT).$(TARGET)`. So, on the first invocation, when make parses the Makefile, it discovers that it needs it to build target `gateway`, it complains that it does not know how to build this prerequisite. Then, it does what it can, that is execute the `webserver` rule, which creates `$(CONTIKI_PROJECT).$(TARGET)` (but too late). On the second invocation it still does not know how to build `$(CONTIKI_PROJECT).$(TARGET)`, but as it is already there everything is fine.

As a quick and dirty hack try, maybe, to add:

```
$(CONTIKI_PROJECT).$(TARGET): webserver
```

to tell make that `$(CONTIKI_PROJECT).$(TARGET)` can be built by executing the `webserver` rule.